# function keeps returning NaN

Tags: c++, math, nan

Hi guys i know what NaN(let me say i know the acronym stands for Not a Number) is but i don't understand why C++ returns it - The following is the approximation of the mathematical constant e - When using the debugger the functions evaluate fine, it's when writing to the console that it returns NaN

Thanks for any feedback

```
double Factorial(int k)
{
    if(k == 0)
        return 1;

    int value = 1;
    for(int i = k; i > 0; i--)
        value *= k;
    return value;
}

double e(int p)
{
    double value = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        value += 1/Factorial(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: you're missing a return statement in your e function.

Comment: Test value for p = 1 result = NaN

Comment: The code you've posted is not legitimate.  Please post a minimal, complete and correct example.

Comment: below your for loop in e, you should probably have something like `return value;`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone - Now i feel like a real moron - i've been looking at this code for the past ten minutes and could not figure out whats up! thanks!

Comment: That is a terrible way to compute a power series, though! You should think about something that updates terms incrementally.

Comment: @AidenStrydom You probably got downvoted because your compiler was surely warning you and you chose to ignore the warnings

Comment: @Kerrek SB - how would you do it? i can see why you say it's bad, could you in-lighten me (ps i am not sarcastic)

Comment: @Preatorian - i wrote this code in notepad - part of the assignment is writing code on paper for the exam on monday - I wrote a script for compiling it- i did not think of adding a pause clause to find any warnings, so thanks good point

Comment: Just think about each term, and how each term relates to the previous term...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't return a value in your e function.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an aswer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return value at the end of e. I don't know when c++ stopped warning about missing returns.

Comment: C++ never required diagnostics for functions failing to return a value. But the compiler probably was giving warnings and they were just ignored.