# C++ Problem I get "nan" as output everytime I run my program

Tags: c++, function, nan

I was required to create a program with a function that changes height in feet to height in meters. I made the function and when I cout from the function I get the right value but when I cout it in main I get "nan". I dont understand why the value is not printing. This is my first time using this website so I am sorry if I miss anything.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


double heightInMeters(double feet , double inches)
{
double footToMeter = 0.305;
double inchToMeter = 0.0254;

double heightInMeters = ((footToMeter * feet) + (inchToMeter * inches));
cout << heightInMeters << endl;
}


int main()
{

double feet, inches, calcheight;
char ch;

cout << "Enter your height [Use format ft-in]: ";
cin >> feet >> ch >> inches;

calcheight = heightInMeters(feet, inches);
cout << calcheight << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function keeps returning NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189256/function-keeps-returning-nan)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function here:

```
double heightInMeters(double feet , double inches)
{
   double footToMeter = 0.305;
   double inchToMeter = 0.0254;

   double heightInMeters = ((footToMeter * feet) + (inchToMeter * inches));
   cout << heightInMeters << endl;
}
```

isn't returning anything. That's undefined behavior, what you get here

```
calcheight = heightInMeters(feet, inches);
```

Is most likely just some invalid rubbish value then. Perhaps instead of this:

```
cout << heightInMeters << endl;
```

You wanted this:

```
return heightInMeters;
```

Does your compiler issue any warnings for your code? If not, please try to find out if you can set it to give you more warnings. Most compilers usually complain about missing returns.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped alot!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

`heightInMeters` doesn't have an explicit `return` value.

Therefore, since it's not a `void` function (or `main`), the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Didn't your compiler warn you of that? It's an easy spot for a compiler to make in your case, and the current crop of compilers all warn if you turn the warning level up appropriately.

(Granted, NaN is a peculiar manifestation of that undefined behaviour.)

Finally, note that one foot is *exactly* 0.3048 meters. Base your conversion metrics from that. Your values introduce unnecessary imprecision.

Comment: While that is certainly an issue, I doubt the `NaN` return is due to that. More likely his `cin` is reading garbabe to begin with.

Comment: @Zinki: It's plausible in a debug build, I guess?

Comment: Thank you, I added a return and it worked! My compiler didnt warn me. I am using code blocks.

Comment: @KhizarMuhammad: Your last job is to fix the conversion constants; they are inadequate particularly given that you're using a `double`. I'd recode so you only had one constant if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

```
void f()
{
    double a=0.3;
    cout << a << endl;
}
//
// inside main function 
f();
```

---

```
double f()
{
    double a=0.3;
    return a；
}

// inside main function 
cout << f() << endl;
```

Because the return value of your code is not specified, the output is “nan“

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that a "nan" result is guaranteed in this case, which is not so. In fact the value is unspecified and reading it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: The return value isn't just "not specified", which would mean any valid number could be returned, but undefined behaviour, which means _anything_ can happen. What is correct is that you should refuse to even look at the code until the undefined behaviour is fixed.